# What is a crt.cache file and how is it related to the certificate file?

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate

I am taking over a legacy IT infrastructure and I have limited info of it, i.e. I am kind of figuring out. I found the certificates as `.crt` files and inspected the content and they seem correct. Next to every `.crt. file there is a file with the same name but the extension is`crt.cache`instead of`.crt`. Seems the format of this file is not a certificate since I cannot open it with openssl to inspect it.

Do you know what this file is supposed to be?

Thank's!

Comment: What *is* the format of this file?

Comment: It is a binary file. I do not know what is the format (hence this question here).